# Can't get z-index to work for div inside of another div

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, z-index

I'm trying to get a drop down menu to work. It consists of an LI with a DIV that appears when the LI is hovered. I want the parent to be drawn in front of the child so that I can create a tabbed effect with the overlapping borders. I can't get the child to be drawn behind the parent.

The following code has the same problem:

```
<div id="test_1">
    Test 1
    <div id="test_2">
        Test 2
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#test_1 {
    border:1px solid green;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
}

#test_2{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    left:-10px;
    z-index:900;
}
```

The above code will draw test_2 in FRONT of test_1. I want test_2 to be drawn BEHIND test_1. How can I get it to do that? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A positioned container always contains its children. You can't have the content of a container below the container itself. See [this test file](http://phrogz.net/CSS/zIndex.html) that I made (about 7 years ago) showing the situation.

Note in particular that the dark blue div is `z-index:-100`, but doesn't appear below its `z-index:3` parent container, nor below a different `z-index:2` container that is its "uncle" (sibling of its parent).

The `z-index` of an element is only valid with respect to other elements using the same positioned container. Once you set `position:relative` on `test_1` you are causing its `z-index` to be in a different world than the `z-index` of `test_2`. The closest you can do is set `#test_2 { z-index:-1 }` to cause it to appear below the content of `#test_1` (but not below its background).

Comment: To be precise, you can have child elements appear below the direct  **content** of the parent (which is implicitly at `z-index:0`), but you cannot put them below the **background** of the parent element. (This is shown in the test file.)

Comment: @Phrogz +1 I had no idea about that! brilliant z-index example!! Thanks!

Comment: How do the borders work? I really just need the border of the parent to appear in front of the border of the child.

Comment: @Cyrcle This is easy enough for you to test, but the answer is that the borders are the same as the background: the child's borders will always appear over the parent's.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the help. I have an idea of how I can get the effect I want. I'll post back when I get it figured out.

Comment: Figured I'd come back and report what I did. Phrogz comment gave me the clue I needed. What I was trying to do was cover part of the border of the div that was dropping down for the menu, so that it would look like it was part of the tab the user clicked. I put another div directly before the drop-down, and gave that div a width of 100% of the tab, and a z-index higher than the div of the drop-down. This caused part of the drop-down's border to be covered and gave me the effect I needed.

Comment: Well that's pretty wild in your example. I can't even figure out how z-index:-100 in a3 lines up with z-index:100 in a2, but it sure is interesting

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a common example about Bootstrap Modals. Consider that your #test_1 is my .modal-body and your #test_2 is my custom `<select>` box, OK? #test_2 is inside #test_1. Simple as that.

[image]

I just have had to **make sure #test_1 `overflow` computed property is not "auto" or "scroll" or "hidden"**, otherwise, the modal would cut my `<select>` box listing in the middle. My current `.modal-body` overflow is `initial`