# z-index image over backgrounds element

Tags: html, css, z-index

Back to basics, I have a situation whereby I have an image which needs to appear over the background of an element just below it. However, I do not want the image to be over the top of the content of that element, only the element (and background properties) itself:

http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/4twr5/1/

HTML:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />

<div>
    <a href="#">Hello World</a>
</div>
​
```

CSS:

```
img { position: absolute; z-index: 20; }

div { position: relative; top: 45px; z-index: 10; padding: 30px; background: red; }

a { position: relative; z-index: 30; padding: 10px; background: yellow; display: block; }
```

Expected behaviour would be the image to appear over the top of the div background *[check]*, but then appear behind the yellow link, which it isn't.

Comment: so you want the image to be in background of the hello world element ?

Comment: If you want image in the background? its fixed here : http://jsfiddle.net/4twr5/2/

Comment: want image above the hello world or below??

Comment: the image should appear BELOW "hello world" but ABOVE the red box

Comment: then apply as background-image that google image

Comment: Not an option, in my scenario the HTML is laid out as shown and must stay like that.

Comment: @ChrisNicholson check my jsfiddle

Comment: @ChrisNicholson -- Can you use JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found my "answer" (more confirming my doubts) here [Can't get z-index to work for div inside of another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456234/cant-get-z-index-to-work-for-div-inside-of-another-div). The key sentence being "Once you set position:relative on test_1 you are causing its z-index to be in a **different world** than the z-index of test_2."

It seems the reason I have a problem is because once I have set the image higher than the div, no matter what z-index value I set to the contents of the div it will always be covered. I didn't think z-indexes worked like this, I thought everything was "separate" and so long as a value was higher than a value elsewhere (regardless of parent containers) things would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
img { position: absolute; z-index: 15; }

div { position: relative; top: 45px; z-index: 20; padding: 30px; background: red; }

a {z-index: 30; padding: 10px; background: yellow; display: block; }
​
```

You can try this code. By the way a is a child of div. You don't need to type position: relative; Because you wrote  for div.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4twr5/21/ Look this jsfiddle

Update according to comment http://jsfiddle.net/4twr5/22/

Comment: According to the comments on the original post, he cannot change the HTML, so he can't nest the image in the div.

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas: correct :) although the outcome of that fiddle is how I want it to look eventually.

Comment: @ChrisNicholson check now fiddle

Comment: Haha nice try but still not a valid option I'm afraid. You can probably tell from my example how things are positioned in weird places, that's pretty much how it has to stay.

Comment: @Chris Nicholson-then use RoddyoftheFrozenPeas answer that is most appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

Put the image inside the div like so:

```
<div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
    <a href="#">Hello World</a>
</div>
```

Comment: According to the comments on the original post, he cannot change the HTML, so he can't nest the image in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are pointing out the base truth: in straight up HTML + CSS, this is probably only possible if the `<img>` is inside of the `<div>` and a sibling to `<a>`.

Since you've indicated that you can't change the HTML, you could instead apply a simple JavaScript that would reorder the DOM as necessary for you: `$('div').prepend(​$('img')​​​​);​`. (This is JQuery, by the way.) What this does is it takes the `<img>` and sticks it as the first child in `<div>`.

Of course, if you were to use this in production code, you'd want to append id's to the elements and select off that otherwise you'd have images being stuck into divs willy nilly.

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hC8CP/1/). The JQuery is called `onDomReady()`. The HTML itself is unchanged.