# Different z-index values with jmpress.js

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

My test website looks as follows: 
As you (hopefully) can see the image (of the pope) is above the background but below the "green stripe".

This is because of

```
#wrapper { position: absolute; z-index: 2;  }
```

for the main div.
I now want another div inside to have another z-index (so just the image is above the green stripe), but when I change it with e.g.

```
#norbert, .step, .cast, .cast_pic { position: relative; z-index: 10; }
```

nothing changes. Is this an issue with the script jmpress.js being used, or is it just not possible with css?

Comment: try to force it with !important

Comment: I had a look and if you give #wrapper that holds the image of the pope a very high z-index it will display above the green stripe

Comment: !important doesn't work, and yes a z-index of 6 for #wrapper will render everything above the green stripe. But I just want the image inside the wrapper div to be above, everything else in that wrapper below the stripe... :(

Answer (score 0):

Just remove z-index line from #stripes. The final #stripes will like as

```
#stripes {
    background: url("img/body_stripes.png") no-repeat fixed center 75% transparent;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.98;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but without the z-index line everything will show up above the #stripes (tested with my local file). But I want to just have SOME divs show up above, and some below the stripes. Or did I miss something?

Comment: In that case create a class with a very high z-index. assign this class to the div(s) that you want to show up.

Comment: Yup, already did that, but that's what not working unfortunately. And I don't know if it's just not possible to have a div in another div having a different z-index or if it's something with jmpress.js..

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456234/cant-get-z-index-to-work-for-div-inside-of-another-div

Comment: Thanks, came across that link as well just now. So, it basically is not possible to have a fullscreen overlay over a website but still remain the links etc. clickable at all...

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
pointer-events: none;
```

for now. Which unfortunately doesn't work in IE.