# How to force button, inside of parent div, in front of div. I've tried z-index to no avail

Tags: jquery, css, dom, positioning, z-index

I was wondering if there is a fix.

```
<div id="div1" style="position: fixed; top:0; z-index:1; background:white;">
 </div>

<div id="div2" style="position: absolute; top:100; z-index:0;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="button" style="position: fixed; top:50; z-index:2;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                some text that is longer than the width of the button
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want the `button` in front of `<div id="div1">` and I want the `button` and `<div id="div1">` in front of   `<div id="div2">`. But what I'm getting is `<div id="div1">` in front of the button.

I'm assuming that the reason is because the `button` is nested in the `<div id="div2">` that is behind `<div id="div1">`. Anyone have any ideas besides restructuring?

I am doing this so that the button will scroll on top of the the text when I scroll down on the page.

The text is longer than the width of the button, so I do the whitespace div so you don't see the extra text coming out of the side of the button.

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456234/cant-get-z-index-to-work-for-div-inside-of-another-div) confirms my suspicions I think, but I would like a way around this. Basically I want the `button` in front of `div1` and `div1` in front of `div2`.

Comment: The button is inside div2 which is beneath div1. Therefore, the button is below beneath div1 as well. If an element A is beneath element B, then all descendants of A are also beneath B.

Comment: You could make div1 click-through and transparent.

Comment: your button has position fixed so you can put it outside of div2.

Comment: If you can use Javascript/jQuery, you could make a button inside the table and another identical button outside the table, and have the outer one trigger the inner on click.

Comment: I was hoping to find a workaround, I can't take the button out of the div since the table is generated inside the div by a literal.

Comment: "by a literal" you mean that is comes from a content management system or something?

Comment: So, you want the button to be fixed on top of the page such that any content scrolling up will pass beneath it below a white background...

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504832/in-css-2-1-if-a-parent-establish-a-stacking-context-why-can-the-childrens-tex/16505305#16505305

Comment: @MarcAudet, I create the Literal content in VB.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just get the button on top, remove `position: absolute;` from `div2`.

This might break other things you're trying to do, but...

You can still give a `margin-top: 100px;` which might keep the positioning intact, depending on your context.

If you can change the .net code to alter the HTML structure, this might be easier.

Comment: @blachawk Your original answer was more or less on the right track, you had the right idea of using jQuery to move the button element into the fixed position block element.  Please see my post for my version. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one technique that may be helpful.

Using your existing HTML, I took out your inline styles and used the following CSS:

```css
#div1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    z-index: 1;
}
#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
```

and the following jQuery:

```
$('#div2 input').prependTo($('#div1'));
```

The trick is to move the button out of `#div2` and into `#div1` using jQuery's DOM manipulation function `.prependTo()`.

Styling the CSS is pretty straightforward after that.

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Gv6XQ/

Comment: I like this, but this does some restructuring, that I can't do. But I like this `prependTo()`

Comment: @Marc Audet, Thanks for the feedback!  I just wasn't sure if the OP wanted to try out a solution with jQuery, but I like your work!  Hopefully this is good enough!